# Minimize array elements by multiplying adjacent elements only if the product is less than equal to k

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, min

I recently came across this question in an online assessment.

```
arr = [2,6,2,4] 
k = 15
```

The array elements need to be minimized by multiplying two adjacent elements only and only if their product is less than `k`.

Example:

```
(2,6,2,4)
(2*6,2*4) --> since 12 and 8 are less than k which is 15
(12,8)
```

The following pattern could have also been followed:

```
(2,6,2,4)
(2,6*2,4) 
(2,12,4) --> no . of  elements is 3 which is more than 2 thus non-optimal.
```

I have been stuck on this problem for days.

I tried walking it through the Matrix Chain Multiplication problem, but I am unable to make any headway. The main difference is that in the MCM problem all matrices CAN BE multiplied with each other. There is no case where 2 matrices cannot be multiplied.

Any hints ?

Comment: what about `(2,3,3)` Do you expect `(6,3)` or `(2,9)`? Or doesn't it matter as long as the result has the minumum number of elements? And what about `(1,2,3)` leads to `(6)` right?

Comment: @derpirscher Correct. The elements themselves does not matter, I only have to reduce it to minimum number of elements. You are right for `(1,2,3)` it leads to `6.`

Ofcourse the value of `k` will be given, which decides the limits on the multiplication.

Comment: @derpirscher What is frying my brain, is how do I deal with the changing elements ?

Comment: What is the range of values in the array? Are they all positive? Zeroes allowed? What should be returned if there is no possibility to get values all below `k`, because some initial values are greater than `k` and no product can reduce it?

Comment: Would a modified stack work then? (I'm thinking of reverse-Minesweeper?)

Comment: @trincot No zeroes allowed. Only positive integers. If there can be no product operations, then the return value should be the input array length itself. That is, the array length cannot be decreased. Otherwise, it should be the length of the array that we get after all operations are complete.

Comment: @Neil Could you share some more detail/insights ?

Comment: @ng.newbie, I see that there is some ambiguity in your reply. Can you be clear at what should be returned if *one* value in the array is not less than `k`? Should that one violation be reason to immediately return the array length, or should this single value be considered as one chunk, and should the process still continue?

Comment: @trincot Regardless of the fact whether one single value is less than or greater than `k`, we should return the array length in that case. As the only operation allowed to reduce array elements is multiplication iff the multiplication of 2 adjacent elements are less than or equal to given `k`. Hope it helps. Please let me know.

Comment: Not much clearer. What is the expected outcome for `([16, 2,2,2], 15)`?  2 - because you could still reduce to `[16, 8]`  or `4` because a value violates the upper limit and there must be no reduction done?

Comment: Hmmm...no that remains unclear. Maybe an example. What is expected for `k=10` and `[12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. Is the expected answer 7 or 2?

Comment: Alright, I see @derpirscher is taking over this conversation, I will leave it.

Comment: @trincot You can reduce `[12,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` to a minimum length to `2`. As you can keep multiplying the `1`s to reduce the array. And since `k` limits to `12` we cannot multiply when it comes to `[12,1]`. Is that better ?

Comment: @trincot I'm not *taking over* I just want to understand what OP really wants/needs to be able to suggest a solution ...

Comment: @derpirscher Given the array is `[16,2,2,2]` and `k=15`. The array can only be reduced to about `[16,8]` because further multiplication would be greater than `k` and violate the constraint. Not sure where `4` is coming from.

Comment: @trincot I am just trying my best to understand the problem, I did not intent for anyone to get offended.

Comment: Because @trincot is trying to clarify, whether an array that contains at least one elmeent `> k` can be reduced or not at all

Comment: @derpirscher A single element cannot be reduced. Only reduction operation allowed is via multiplying 2 adjacent elements iff they are less than or equal to `k`.

Comment: @ng.newbie This reminded me of 1d-Minesweeper because the neighbourhood becomes unvisted when you collapse two vertices. I see from the comments that you are not asking that, but I think the really interesting possibilities are a mix of negative and positive.

Comment: @Neil You mean if the question introduced negative numbers ?

Comment: Yes, possibly negative integers and `k`. I think Minesweeper is NP-hard, but I don't know whether there would be an easy solution to this modified optimization problem. You could find the least pair until `k`, maybe?

Comment: @Neil Wouldn't the algorithm be same ? If `k` was positive but the array contained negative numbers ? Would help me if you could provide an example.

Comment: Example that one would need more than one pass: 3, {2,2,-2}. I guess a negative number eats the positives around it provided that, for one of it's neighbours, `p*n<k`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the values of the array are strictly positive, you can use a greedy algorithm: keep multiplying values until a next multiplication would be `k` or more. When that happens, start a new chunk and reset the product to the current array value. This way we put the chunk boundaries as far to the right as possible. We can see that if we would move one chunk boundary more to the left, this would never decrease the number of chunks needed.

Here is an implementation of this greedy algorithm in (simple) JavaScript:

```js
function solve(arr, k) {
    if (arr.length == 0) return 0; // Boundary case
    
    let product = 1;
    let count = 1;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        product = product * arr[i];
        if (product >= k) { // Start a new chunk
            product = arr[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

// Example run
const arr = [2,6,2,4]; 
const k = 15;
const result = solve(arr, k);
console.log("Number of chunks", result);
```

If we would allow 0 as possible array value, and `k` is strictly positive, then the occurrence of a zero would lead to the result 1: all values can be multiplied to one product which is 0.

This algorithm would no longer work correctly if negative array values would be allowed.

Comment: What is the reason behind `if (arr[i] >= k) return arr.length;` Just because one element cannot be multiplied, that doesn't mean the array can't be shortended (at least I can't see anything like that in OPs question or comments). Imagine and input like `[15, 1, 1, 1]` which can be reduced to `[15,1]`

Comment: @derpirscher, I asked about the case where a single value would violate the condition regarding `k` and they answered that in this case the array length should be returned.

Comment: @trincot I really like the solution, but I cannot understand why greedy works. Let's say you can multiply with both on your left or right side, which do you choose ?

Comment: Comment from OP *If there can be no product operations, then the return value should be the input array length itself. That is, the array length cannot be decreased.* But my example can be decreased ... Just because one particulare value cannot be multiplied, that doesnt mean, there are *no product operations*

Comment: @trincot For example: {3,6,2} k = 20. We can go with 3*6 or 6*2, why choose the greedy one ?

Comment: @ng.newbie Because you said it doesn't matter. They both lead to the same result, ie 2 ...

Comment: @derpirscher In this example it does not. But I cannot convince myself that going any way will lead to the global minimum, which is why I was trying to use some form of DP.

Comment: @derpirscher But in my original example: {2,6,2,4} k = 12 if I multiplied the  middle 6*2 then it would lead to a sub-optimal result as compared to if I multiplied the first and second element.

Comment: @ng.newbie But the greedy approach would never come to that situation, because it would multiply  2*6 ... But, I'm not entirely sure  myself, the greedy approach is guaraneed to always return the optimum.

Comment: @derpirscher Exactly, how can I be sure ? I thinking of brute forcing some examples.

Comment: @ng.newbie Brute force analysis can never prove anything in an infinite problem space (ie you cannot check all possible inputs and check if the algorithm works), only contradict something (ie you find one example where it doesn't work)

Comment: @derpirscher Yes but if I find one example that doesn't work can't I say that the greedy approach is not correct ?

Comment: I removed the boundary condition for values greater than k. This was based on a misunderstanding. Apparently you want violations of the `k` limit to become a chunk on their own, despite they break the rule.

Comment: Yes, if you find one example that doesn't return the minimum, you can say, this algorithm is not correct ...

Comment: For what it is worth, in my answer I already reasoned that putting the chunk boundary somewhere else cannot improve the solution: having *more* terms to deal with cannot *reduce* the number of chunks for them. This is why a greedy solution works.

Comment: @trincot Which rule is it breaking ? Please can you add more details ? A single element cannot be reduced as there are no elements to multiply it with. Does it help ?

Comment: Well it is a boundary case. A single value is already a "product" with just 1 term. But it doesn't matter, as long as the rules are clear. And now it is clear that when one element is not less than `k` it should become its own chunk. No problem. All clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this question in an OA as well. I don't want to write the code out again but the intuition is you can just slide a window of size 2 from left to right and multiply the numbers and replace them if you can. So: for every adjacent pair, if l*r <= k, set the r value to the multiplied number. Then, set the l value to None or Null or whatever you want. update the l window to move it to the right by 1. Then, just find the difference between the original arr size and the number of null vals. All cases passed

Answer (score -1):

Context - I just gave an online test on hackerrank website because I'm going through an online screening process for an interview and this question was bestowed upon my small brain and watery eyes.

I failed to solve this particular problem because it was timed and ofc. my brain had stopped then. After the exam ended I jumped into it right away and wrote some code that I have mentioned below.

Please forgive me if this problem is not completely solved, I just checked the test cases that were visible to me, others were locked so couldn't check.

```cpp
int reduceArr(vector<int> a, int k){
    int count=0;

    while(true){
        bool isSmallFound = false;
        int prod = 0;

        if(a.size() > 1){
            prod = a[0] * a[1];
        }else{
            return a.size();
        }

        if(prod <= k){
            isSmallFound = true;
            a.erase(a.begin());
            a.erase(a.begin());
            a.push_back(prod);
            count++;
        }

        if(!isSmallFound){
            return a.size();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a = {2,1,3,1}, a2={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, a3 = {2,6,2,4};
    int k=6, k2=90, k3=15;
    cout<<reduceArr(a, k);
}
```